# Completely disable the Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

I have used the 'Embed In' navigation controller within the storyboard. Is there a way to completely disable the whole navigation bar? I have tried the code below, but when there is a swipe, the navigation bar appears again. I want to be able to completely hide the whole bar until a condition is met. Is there a way to do this?

```
  self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
  self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
```

I have tried a custom navigation bar, but I couldn't get a nice scroll effect like with the default navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the `navigationBar` just do:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

Add this row in your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Hi @Rashwan L, when I put that into the viewDidLoad I am getting "Value of type 'UINavigationBar' has no member 'isHidden'" - I have the UIViewController class and it won't let me add the NavigationBar class (or other navigation classes), is there a way around this?

Comment: That´s weird... Try to clean your project and restart Xcode.

Comment: try "hidden" if you're using swift 2

Comment: From apple's docs: `To show or hide the navigation bar, you should always do so through the navigation controller by changing its isNavigationBarHidden property or calling the setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:) method.`  See my answer below.

Comment: @alex +1, if you´re using Swift 2 use `hidden` instead of `isHidden` EAS.

Comment: "hidden" is showing up. I am using Swift 2, sorry I didn't state that. If I scroll down, then back up to the top, when scrolling up again, the navigation bar is showing up. Do I need to intercept the swipe input and then disable the nav bar? I am currently using these classes: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate

Comment: No it should be enough to set `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true` in your `viewDidLoad`. Remove all other codes for the navigationBar.

Comment: Yes thank you, I did a search for my nav bar and found other places I had been trying things out. Thanks for your help, I have been trying to figure this out for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in viewDidLoad:

`self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)`

Comment: Hi @creeperspeak, thanks, this also works, I found other places that were showing the nav bar in the code.